# While calculating Haversine distance, the main for loop is running only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, haversine

I have a data frame consisting of city names, longitudes and latitudes. What I want to do is create a data frame of cities around a city in a 100km radius. What I mean by this is that If my data looks like

```
City    Latitude Longitude
Delhi       lat1     long1
Noida       lat2     long2 
Gurgaon     lat3     long3
Mumbai      lat4     long4
```

After processing I want my data to look like:

```
City    nearby city  distance
Delhi       Noida       x1
Delhi       Gurgaon     x2
Noida       Delhi       x3 
Noida       Gurgaon     x4
Gurgaon     Delhi       x5
Gurgaon     Noida       x6
```

Mumbai gets omitted from this because of the condition that I only want to see the cities around a city within a 100km radius of said city. For this reason I'm using Haversine formula. Here is my code:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(city_list):
    lat1 = city_latitude[idx]
    long1 = city_longitude[idx]
    for next_idx, next_val in enumerate(copy_city_list):
        if val == next_val:
            pass
        else:
            lat2 = city_latitude[next_idx]
            long2 = city_longitude[next_idx]
            lat1, long1, lat2, long2 = map(radians, [lat1, long1, lat2, long2])
            # haversine formula
            dlon = long2 - long1
            dlat = lat2 - lat1
            a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
            c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
            # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
            km = 6371 * c
            if(km > 100):
                pass
            else:
                city.append(val)
                near_by_city.append(next_val)
                distance.append(km)
    print("Record appeneded")
```

I split my data into 3 lists, `city_list`,`city_latitude`,`city_longitude` because when I first did it using a pandas dataframe, I got an output after nearly 10 minutes as I have 3368 records. Splitting it into lists and performing the calculations is giving me an output in 2-3 minutes but the issue remains the same. The main loop only performs one iteration out of 3368 and the appended values are also getting jumbled.

The output I want to see is `Delhi,Delhi,Noida,Noida,Gurgaon,Gurgaon` in my `city` list and `Noida,Gurgaon,Delhi,Gurgaon,Delhi,Noida` in my `near_by_city` list. Instead I see `Noida,Gurgaon` in my `city` list and `Delhi,Delhi` in my `near_by_city` list.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you temporarily remove the condition that cities have to be less than 100km apart. Do all the combinations show up with the right distances?

Comment: What exactly is `copy_city_list`?  Your results are consistent with that list containing only Delhi, rather than actually being the full list of cities.

Comment: @quamrana, Yes, when the condition is removed the information is getting appended into the desired lists

Comment: @jasonharper ```copy_city_list``` is a copy of the list ```city_list```. Its not consistent with that for Delhi either as I want the ```city``` list to store the two occurences of Delhi but currently the information that should be in the ```near_by_city``` list is getting stored in the current ```city``` list.

Comment: You should update your question with the contents of: `city_list, copy_city_list, city_latitude and city_longitude`.

Comment: How exactly did you make that copy?  And *why* are you making a copy at all - that's necessary when modifying a list that you're iterating over, but it seems pointless here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easier to just use your city_data without breaking it into separate lists.

I like list comprehensions so I am going to use one to cross product the list of cities with itself and calculate the distance between them. Then we will print only the pairs that are nearby each other.

There are likely some optimizations to be had for example, if you know the distance from "A" to "B" then you might not need to calculate the distance form "B" to "A". I leave that to you to think about.

```
from haversine import haversine

cities = [
    ["Delhi", 28.7041, 77.1025],
    ["Noida", 28.5355, 77.3910],
    ["Gurgaon", 28.4595, 77.0266],
    ["Mumbai", 19.0760, 72.8777]
]

cities_crossed = [
    [x[0], y[0], haversine((x[1], x[2]), (y[1], y[2]))]
    for x in cities
    for y in cities if x[0] != y[0]
]

print("City\tNearby\tDistance")
for nearby_cities in [city_pair for city_pair in cities_crossed if city_pair[2] < 100]:
    print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(*nearby_cities))
```